# creating a square

Tags: python, string, for-loop

I need to create a square with certain height and length in python. The code should take this two parameters and print a box with the letters O and I, alternating them. It has to alternate with what letter yeah row starts. it should look something like this

```
>>>square(5,5) 
OIOIO
IOIOI
OIOIO
IOIOI
OIOIO
# Note how each row and each column alternate! 
>>> square(5,10)
OIOIOIOIOI
IOIOIOIOIO
OIOIOIOIOI
IOIOIOIOIO
OIOIOIOIOI
>>> square(2,4) 
OIOI
IOIO
```

so far I have this but I honestly do not know how to make it alternate and how to modify the height

```
def square(height, length):
    a='square'
    c=(height/2)
    num=0
    symbol='OI'
    while a=='square' and int(num)<int(c):
        num+=1
        print(symbol*int(c))
```

it is suggested to use a for loop inside another for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generator expressions, `str.join` and `itertools.cycle()`.

**Example:**

```
from __future__ import print_function


from itertools import cycle


try:
    range = xrange  # Python 2/3 compatibility
except NameError:
    pass


def square(height, width, symbols="OI"):
    it = cycle(symbols)
    return "\n".join("".join(next(it) for _ in range(width)) for _ in range(height))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> print(square(2, 4))
OIOI
OIOI
>>> print(square(5, 5))
OIOIO
IOIOI
OIOIO
IOIOI
OIOIO
```

> Using `itertools.cycle()` also ensures that the pattern also changes
>   per row.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function to get the character at each position and .join to form a line

```
def charAt(x, y):
    return "O" if (x+y)%2==0 else "I"

def square(x_size, y_size):
    for x in range(x_size):
        print "".join([charAt(x, y) for y in range(y_size)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this which is certainly not the best way to do it, but an intuitive one. Read the comments:

```
def square(height, width):
    symbols = "OI"  ## The characters to use.
    result = ""     ## Where we will collect each row.

    for row in range(height):
        current_row = ""
        for column in range(width):
            ## This line is to alternate between I's and O's
            ## using the parity of the current column:
            symbol_to_use = symbols[column%2]

            current_row += symbol_to_use
        result += current_row + "\n"

    ## The [:-1] bit is to remove the last "\n" (newline):
    return result[:-1]
```